# Script runs on multiple column loop how to post back only once, not every column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My function works well

It finds a column by its header then tt splits the cell values in a column on a diameter than replaces the values of the fragments and then rejoins them into a string

and repeats for all the columns in the list of headers

It is kinda long winded but I am surprised I made it work as well as it does

My issue I would like assistance with is that it posts back on every Header, how do you get it to post back only once?

I have tried to figure this out but to no avail

Thanks

```
function FindRsplace(shtName, frshtName, cheaders, frheaders, dilm1, dilm2) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(shtName);
  var hn =[];
  var fhn = [];

  //Array of column indices from column headers
  for (var k = 0; k <= cheaders.length-1; k++) {

       hn[k] = HTN(shtName,cheaders[k]) - 1;

       fhn[k] = HTN(frshtName,frheaders[k]);

  }

 for (var j = 0; j <= cheaders.length-1; j++) {

 var frSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(frshtName);
 var frLR = GLR(frshtName,frheaders[j],2);  // Get the last row of the Search column NOT of the Sheet
 var frRange = frSheet.getRange(2, fhn[j], frLR, 2);
 var frValues = frRange.getValues(); 

 // Read Height only once
 var maxHeight = Range.getLastRow();

 // Read all values and formulas at once
 var rangeValues = Range.getValues();

 // iterate through all cells in the selected range Look in Sheet
for (var cellRow = 0; cellRow < maxHeight; cellRow++) {
for (var i = 0; i < frValues.length; i++) {

        //FindReplace string fragments
        rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]] = rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]].toString().split(frValues[i][0]+dilm1).join(frValues[i][1]+dilm2).trim();

        //Replaceing the last fragment or the only string without dilimeter
        rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]] = rangeValues[cellRow][hn[j]].toString().split(frValues[i][0]).join(frValues[i][1]).trim();

   }
 }

  Range.setValues(rangeValues);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 } 
}

function FindRsplace_n() {

   FindRsplace(
  'sheet1', 'FindReplace',
  ["HeaderA", "HeaderB", "HeaderC"], 
  ["frHeaderA", "frHeaderB", "frHeaderC"]],
    ",",
   "|"
    );
 }
```

Comment: You're gonna have to tell us what HTN and arrListConCatFindRsplace do. It looks like you have open quotes without end quotes in the parameter list for arrListConCatFindRsplace.

Comment: sorry those were oversites, HTN gets the column index from the header name

Comment: Make sure you write your code in a self-consistent style - that will help you to remember what is happening after 1 hour/day/week/year of not looking at it and then needing to fix or change something. A very common practice is to increase indentation levels when you nest code blocks (such as a statement within a `for` loop).